# Hybris - customersupportadministratorrole vs customersupportadministratorgroup

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, commerce

What is the difference between ***customersupportadministratorrole*** and ***customersupportadministratorgroup*** in sample data provided by Hybris?
Both records are available in "**UserGroups**" item type. But not sure when to use ***customersupportadministratorrole*** vs ***customersupportadministratorgroup***?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In general roles are more fine-grained, and groups aggregate 1+ roles.  Typically the users are only ever direct members of the groups.  In this case *customersupportadministratorrole* is a BackOfficeRole giving access to certain components/configurations that are exclusive to that role.  Then *customersupportadministratorgroup* is a member of that role + several other roles.  If you look at the example impexes, users (e.g. *CustomerSupportAdministrator* are setup as members of the group.